# Ordenar Hojas en xlsx

Tags: python

Tengo xlsx con tres hojas y un código para ordenarlas pero quiero ordenarlas a mi manera y no por nombre:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet_names = ['Data1', 'Chart1', 'Data2', 'Chart2', 'Data3', 'Chart3']
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

# sort sheets based on name
workbook.worksheets_objs.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)
workbook.close()
```

Distribucion que necesito:

```
sheet_names = ['Data1', 'Chart1', 'Chart3', 'Chart2', 'Data3', 'Data2']
```

Comment: Martín, por que tienes que ordenarlos? no puedes crearlos ya con el orden que desesas?

Comment: No sabia que podia crearlos con otro orden, como se hace? @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Entiendo, que cuando haces `workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)` las hojas se van agregando en el orden en que lo has definido en `sheet_names`. Si ya estableces esta lista con el orden que deseas debiera ser suficiente.